pg_cron is not triggering a scheduled task at the intended time, despite successful scheduling
I have a PostgreSQL database hosted on Supabase, and I am trying to schedule a task to decrement the number of days in a subscriptions table at a specific time each day using pg_cron. The task is successfully scheduled and visible in the cron.job table, but it never executes at the scheduled time.
Here is what I have set up:

Trigger function executed after an insert in the subscriptions table:

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER after_subscription_insert
AFTER INSERT ON subscriptions
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.schedule_decrement_job();


Function to schedule the pg_cron (activated in Supabase extentions) task:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.schedule_decrement_job()
RETURNS TRIGGER 
SET search_path TO ''
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  job_id int;
BEGIN
  -- Delete the old task if it exists
  SELECT jobid INTO job_id
  FROM cron.job
  WHERE jobname = 'decrement_subscription_' || NEW.id;

  IF job_id IS NOT NULL THEN
    PERFORM cron.unschedule(job_id);
  END IF;

  -- Schedule a new task to decrement the number of days at updated_at time (truncated)
  PERFORM cron.schedule(
    'decrement_subscription_' || NEW.id,
    concat(EXTRACT(minute FROM NEW.updated_at), ' ', EXTRACT(hour FROM NEW.updated_at), ' * * *'),
    'SELECT public.decrement_days(''' || NEW.id || ''');'
  );

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;



decrement_days function to decrement number_of_days in the subscriptions table:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.decrement_days(subscription_id UUID)
RETURNS void
SET search_path TO ''
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  -- Decrement the number of days, but do not go below 0
  UPDATE public.subscriptions
  SET number_of_days = GREATEST(number_of_days - 1, 0),
      updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  WHERE id = subscription_id AND number_of_days > 0;
END;
$$;

ISSUE :

When I manually execute the decrement_days function, it works as expected, and number_of_days is correctly decremented.

The task is properly scheduled, and I can see it in the cron.job table:
SELECT * FROM cron.job WHERE jobname = 'decrement_subscription_<id>';


Here is an example of the result:
jobid : 23
schedule : 35 10 * * *
command : SELECT public.decrement_days('cfc0a27e-4303-428f-811c-768c29b1d053');
nodename : "localhost"
nodeport : 5432
database : "postgres"
username : "service_role"
active : true
jobname : decrement_subscription_cfc0a27e-4303-428f-811c-768c29b1d053


Problem Encountered: The task scheduled at 10:35 never runs. I checked the logs, and there seems to be no error reported at the scheduled time. The tasks are properly listed in cron.job, but they don't trigger at the specified time.

What I Have Tried:
1. Permissions Check:

I verified that the service_role user has the necessary permissions. I granted SELECT, UPDATE, and DELETE permissions on the cron.job table to this user.
I also used SET ROLE service_role to test permissions manually, and I was able to execute the function without error.

2. Manual Trigger Test:
When I manually call the decrement_days function via SQL, it works perfectly, and number_of_days is correctly decremented.
3. Schedule Verification:
I modified the task's schedule several times (e.g., every minute for testing with * * * * *), but it still didn't work.
4. Debugging Messages:
I added RAISE NOTICE messages in the decrement_days function to confirm that it was being executed, but I saw no indication that the function was triggered by pg_cron at the scheduled time.
5. Time Zone Check:
I verified the server's time zone with SHOW timezone;, and everything seems correct (UTC).
I also tried scheduling with time zone conversion, but it still didn't help.
Question:
Why isn't pg_cron triggering the scheduled task at the intended time, even though it is listed in the cron.job table? Is there something I'm missing regarding permissions, roles, or the configuration of pg_cron on Supabase? Any suggestions on how to further debug this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
